# Different responses from Spyder's Ipython and standard anaconda console

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder, xgboost

I have a very large script which I developed using Spyder. I have friends who are trying to run it using the standard anaconda console / command prompt. What is interesting is the the script works between computers if run on Spyder, but completely freaks out if run in the anaconda console, command prompt, or even Ipython outside of Spyder. When I say freak out, I mean it randomly starts again at the beginning of the script, reloads packages, spams the user interface text a few times then randomly crashs. There is never an error code. There is no while loop or for loop or anything which would cause it to restart randomly like this. I have had a number of python programmers look at the code directly and cannot understand either why it would even attempt to restart.

I have isolated the issue to the following line:

```
    results = pd.DataFrame(MOR.predict(dat), columns = scores)
```

In this case, MOR is an imported pickled sklearn multioutput xgboost model. dat is a dataframe with a couple rows and the same required columns as the xgboost model. scores is simply a list of names which is equal to the number of output variables from the sklearn model.

Any ideas as to why this script would run perfectly in spyder but not the console? Note, its clear that this likely will not have a solved answer, but any speculations as to why spyder would behave different from these other consoles?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We have several customizations in our consoles that are not available in a regular Python interpreter or in IPython. They are located [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/3.x/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py) and [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/3.x/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py). My advise is: Try to determine what piece of code is responsible for your code behaving correctly in Spyder and move it directly to your own code.

Comment: Since you isolated the problem to creating a dataframe, the most likely Spyder customization related to that should be [this one](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/3.x/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py#L280-L303)